# How to make a flutter chart line chart?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[this is my current graph look's like but i want to make tickProviderSpec as the average line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t99s4.jpg)

This is what i have done. Is that possible to make a white line at the Center of line chart. Currently, Im using StaticNumericTickProviderSpec to draw the average line. I only need one average line in my line chart. Any idea to do this?

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
class WeightTracker_time_series_chart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;
  WeightTracker_time_series_chart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  factory WeightTracker_time_series_chart.withSampleData() {
    return new WeightTracker_time_series_chart(
      _createSampleData(),
      animate: false,
    );
  }
  List getdata =["1","2","3"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new charts.LineChart(seriesList,

        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig( includeArea: true,
          includePoints: true,
          includeLine: true,
          stacked: true,),
        layoutConfig: charts.LayoutConfig(
            leftMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(60),
            topMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(10),
            rightMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(0),
            bottomMarginSpec: charts.MarginSpec.fixedPixel(20)
        ),
        flipVerticalAxis: false,
        defaultInteractions: false,
        behaviors: [new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior()],
        domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
          viewport: new charts.NumericExtents(20, 120),
            renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                  color: charts.MaterialPalette.white,
                  thickness: 1,
                )
            ),

            tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(
              // Create the ticks to be used the domain axis.
                _createTickSpec(),
            )),
        selectionModels: [
          new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
              changedListener: (SelectionModel model) {
                print( model.selectedSeries[0].measureFn(
                    model.selectedDatum[0].index));
                }
          )
        ],

        primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
            renderSpec:
            charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                labelOffsetFromAxisPx: 20,

                labelAnchor: charts.TickLabelAnchor.before,
                lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                  color: charts.MaterialPalette.white,
                  thickness: 2,
                )
            ),
            tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(

              // Create the ticks to be used the domain axis.
              <charts.TickSpec<num>>[


                new charts.TickSpec(50, label: '80 ', style: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 14)),

              ],
            )

        ),
        
  }

  List<charts.TickSpec<num>> _createTickSpec() {
    List<charts.TickSpec<num>> _tickProvidSpecs = new List<charts.TickSpec<num>>();
    double d = 0;
    double day= 0;
   for(int i = 0; i< getdata.length ; i++) {

      _tickProvidSpecs.add(new charts.TickSpec(d,label: '$day%', style: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 14)));
      d +=20;
      day+=1;
    }

   return _tickProvidSpecs;
  }


  static List<charts.Series<day_kg, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final myFakeDesktopData = [
      new day_kg(0, 70),
      new day_kg(20, 85),
      new day_kg(40, 80),

    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<day_kg, int>(
        id: 'weight',
        fillColorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.white,
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (day_kg data, _) => data.date,
        measureFn: (day_kg data, _) => data.kg,

        domainLowerBoundFn: (day_kg data, _) => data.domainLower,

        measureLowerBoundFn: (day_kg data, _) => data.measureLower,
        strokeWidthPxFn: (_, __) => 4,
        data: myFakeDesktopData,
      ),


    ];
  }

}

class day_kg {
  final int date;
  final int kg;

  final int domainUpper = 100;
  final int domainLower = 0;

  final int measureUpper = 100;
  final int measureLower = 0;

  day_kg(this.date, this.kg);
}
```

Comment: You can use these libraries: 1.https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart 2.https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts

Comment: my SDK environment cannot support fl_chart

Comment: why? whats the problem?

Comment: it cannot be used in the ios platform. i dont know what is the actual error yet. btw i almost done the graph by using the old plugin. I only left the average line do you have any idea?